# Proof that for two perpendiicular cords intersecting at P $PA+PB+PC+PD=2PO$ using vectors, O being the center.

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

[image]

To prove $\overline{PA}+\overline{PB}+\overline{PC}+\overline{PD}=2\overline{PO}$

I've been able to do

$$\begin{align}
\overline{PA}+\overline{PB}+\overline{PC}+\overline{PD} & =  \overline{PO}+\overline{OA}+\overline{PO}+\overline{OB}+\overline{PO}+\overline{OC}+\overline{PO}+\overline{OD} \\
 & = 4\overline{PO}+\overline{OA}+\overline{OB}+\overline{OC}+\overline{OD} \\
 & = 2\overline{PO}+2\overline{PO}+\overline{OA}+\overline{OB}+\overline{OC}+\overline{OD}
\end{align}$$
So how can I prove $\overline{OA}+\overline{OB}+\overline{OC}+\overline{OD}=2\overline{OP}$ so that it cancels with the $2\overline{PO}$ above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Let $X$ and $Y$ be the orthogonal projections of $O$ at $CD$ and $AB$ respectively.
- Then, $PX = \frac{PC+PD}{2}$ and $PY = \frac{PA+PB}{2}$.
- However, $PO = PX + PY$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Sir, why is 2nd point true?

Comment: @MichaelLi Because $X$ is the midpoint of $CD$ and $Y$ is the midpoint of $AB$, the choice of $P$ is irrelevant. Another argument might be, because the diagonals of a [parallelogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram) (here its two sides are $PC$ and $PD$) bisect each other.

Comment: Dropping perpendiculars, never thought of that, thanks.